Docker - 429 Too Many Requests
I have a purchased VPS server running Ubuntu on which I have a Docker container running a Python Django application and I recently paid for the server one day late. After starting the server, all the files were properly in place, however, trying to run the build returns an error:
failed to solve: python:3.12: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.12: unexpected status from HEAD request to https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/python/manifests/3.12: 429 Too Many Requests

I read a bit about this on the internet and about the need to create a docker account and log in to the server with the "docker login" command, but this also returns an error:
Waiting for authentication in the browser… Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ failed with status: 429 Too Many Requests

Everything worked fine before. Re-installing the whole system did not help. Has anyone else had a similar problem?

Did you install Docker Desktop or the docker engine?

I have a similar problem.
Docker Hub uses the first 64 bits of your IPv6 address to handle rate limiting functionality:
https://www.docker.com/blog/beta-ipv6-support-on-docker-hub-registry/
here you can see the relevant part
You can find a discussion here:
https://github.com/ubicloud/ubicloud/discussions/2244#discussioncomment-11231599
I disabled IPv6 in my VPS and can now log in again.
Bye!

Hi and welcome to ServerFault. Linking to external information is not as good as summarising that information in your answer, since external links may cease to work.
